# Create/edit Vagrant base box to pre-install cookbooks

Tags: ruby, chef-infra, virtual-machine, vagrant

My VM takes about 10 minutes to boot because of all the cookbooks it needs to install.

I'm looking for a way to edit an existing (or create a new) base box where I can have all the required cookbooks installed. So every time I boot my VM, the cookbooks will already be installed and I won't have to wait too long.

Is this possible?

If so, could someone please point me in the right direction?

I'm currently using the Lucid32 base box.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Sounds like you need to tune your base box so install everything you need in a vagrant box and export this box as your new base box:

```
vagrant halt; vagrant package; vagrant box add new_basebox package.box
```

See [here](http://docs.vagrantup.com/v1/docs/base_boxes.html) for more details on packaging, esp. the last section.

Answer (score 0):

In Vagrant v2, you can use the following command to package the VM

```
vagrant package
```